# Is the final keyword a type qualifier in Java?

Tags: java, keyword

In Java when I use this statement:

```
final int nr = 10;
```

I stay declaring a **constant**.

In books on other languages like, e.g., C# or C++ we can use `const`.

The keyword `const` is said to be a ***type qualifier*** because it is an attribute that modifies and refines the properties of a variable.

So a statement like `const int nr = 10;` is a ***constant integer*** because
"const qualified int".

However in JLS is never cited `final` as type qualifier but it is indicated, generally, as a a ***modifier*** (***type modifier?***).

But modifier of what? of the variable? of the type?

So, at the end, my question is: **is final a type qualifier?**

Comment: of a method, a class, a variable. There is more than one suitable case for the `final` modifier.

Comment: *is final a type qualifier*: How would it be possible to answer that, since "type qualifier" isn't a thing in Java?

Comment: Yes, but my question relate to the case where final is applied to a variable.

Comment: The moral of this story is: don't expect every language to use the exact same terminology. Note that `final int nr` isn't a constant in Java in the same way that `const int nr` would be in C#... you'd need to make it `static final` for that to be the case.

Comment: @Tunaki, yes but into JSL is a modifier... supposedly of a type?

Comment: @xdevel2000: No, it's a modifier for the *field*. That's why it's discussed under "field modifiers": http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

Comment: @JonSkeet, this is a good hint! So for JLS final is a "field modifier" not a type modifier like in C#. So is readonly in C# a field modifier?

Comment: @xdevel2000: Have you consulted the C# specification? (What makes you think `const` is a type modifier in C#?)

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes you are right into C# spec is written: "constant modifier". But, at this point, why "type qualifier" has a meaning only in C/C++? If in C# I write const int a = 100; am I not saying that a is a "contant integer"?

Comment: @xdevel2000: Yes, but that's not changing the *type* of `a`. Whereas in C++, it's part of the type - it affects what you can do with a value, rather than just what you can do with the *variable*.

Answer (score 6):

There are no such things as *type qualifiers* in Java.

When `final` is used in the context of declaring a variable, it merely states that something else cannot be assigned to that variable.

For a primitive type like `int`, that *effectively* makes it analogous to the `const` of C++.

For a *reference* type, it means that you can't re-use that variable to refer to a different object. But you can still *modify* that object through the `final` reference.